# If we generalize clojure function juxt to juxe, that is juxe returns a hash map instead of vector, will this function juxe be useful?

Tags: clojure

In some functional programming books, they define tuple as the form [a b c] and entity as the form {:a x :b y :c z}.

If we take the `t` in `juxt` as the idea of tuple, can we have a higher order function name `juxe` with `e` as the idea of entity?

Therefore, the behavior of juxe will be like

```
((juxe :a a :b b :c c) x) => {:a (a x) :b (b x) :c (c x)}
```

Will this function `juxe` be useful?

Some background ideas of this question. I consider there are three types of higher order functions in Clojure:

- type 1: higher order template functions
  `map, filter, reduce, take-nth, group-by`
- type 2: higher order decorate functions
  `partial, comp, juxt`
- type 3: `#( ... %1 %2)`

I usually uses type 3 to achieve many things that type 2 can also do because I feel the readability of type 3 is better. However, I feel the functions of type 2 really expand my imagination and for me, it is the real value of them.

Also, the recently release of datomic query now support to return set of entity. Originally it can only return set of tuple.

Comment: I'd check the usual suspects of util libraries in the clojureverse.  If it's there someone considered it usefull.  And if it's usefull _for you_ why not just write it and use it?  Yet i close-voted.

Comment: [This *Clojure Cookbook* page](https://github.com/clojure-cookbook/clojure-cookbook/blob/master/02_composite-data/2-21_applying-functions-to.asciidoc) gives several translations of sequence functions to apply to maps. Your function is not among them,since it also deals with a applying a collection of functions to constant data.

Answer (score 1):

```
(defn juxe [& kf-pairs]
  (let [pairs (partition 2 kf-pairs)
        [ks fs] (apply mapv vector pairs)]
    (fn [x] (zipmap ks (map #(% x) fs)))))
```

For example,

```
=> ((juxe :a inc :b dec :c -) 99)
{:a 100, :b 98, :c -99}
```